# How can I prevent a particular user from using neither LAN nor WLAN

Tags: networking, xubuntu, network-manager, autostart

This question pertains to Xubuntu, in particular to Xubuntu 22.04 if that matters.

I want to set a user account on my Xubuntu 22.04 computer for backup operations.
For safety reasons, all network functions shall be disabled for this user. The solution I am looking for does not have to be secure against malicious attacks. It should only ensure that all network communication is switched off by default after you have logged into this account.

I want the state as if I had switched off all network in `nm-applet`.
Help of `nm-applet` says that it is not meant to be used from scripts.
`nm-applet` would normally be started through the autostart mechanism (`~/.config/autostart`).

I prevented `nm-applet` from being started this way, but I see, the LAN is operational by default unless I start `nm-applet` and switch it off there (or all network together).

How can I control the on and off state of the LAN and the WLAN interface together programmatically, e.g. by a script to be run through `~/.config/autostart`?

Comment: In the past I've just had specific users traffic routed to a *sink* instead of a *gateway*. If the user has `sudo` rights they can run a command (*or script*) which will revert that, but my intention was only to deny internet access by default & this achieved my aim.  (*if not obvious; it was part of user user config; which can be set via gui tool OR SCRIPT as you wish; you could give them network address/range different to others or something your routers will route nowhere/as-required; i wanted them to have network but not external*)

Answer (score 0):

According to the German Wikipedia (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetworkManager), `nmcli` is the command line interface of the package `network-manager`.

Looking through `man nmcli` I found out that

```
nmcli networking off
```

is the thing I was looking for.

So in order to switch off network for this particular user, I have to add a line

```
sh -c 'nmcli networking off'
```

to the tab **Application Autostart** in `xfce4-session-settings`.

Surprisingly, switching the network off this way also has an effect on other users after changing over to them: Therefore, one should add a line

```
sh -c 'nmcli networking on'
```

to their tab **Application Autostart** in their `xfce4-session-settings`.

Bingo!